# Rendering a Vertex Buffer DirectX11

Tags: c++, directx-11, vertex-buffer

Hi I have a VertexBuffer

```
ID3D11Buffer* VB;
```

And its contents are being initialized here:

```
bool TestApp::Init()
{
    if (!DXApp::Init())
    {
        return false;
    }

    VERTEX verts[3] =
    {
        VERTEX(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f),
        VERTEX(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),
        VERTEX(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),
    };

    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC bufferDesc;
    bufferDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    bufferDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof(VERTEX) * 3;
    bufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
    bufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    bufferDesc.MiscFlags = 0;

    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA InitData;
    InitData.pSysMem = verts;
    InitData.SysMemPitch = 0;
    InitData.SysMemSlicePitch = 0;

    m_pDevice->CreateBuffer(&bufferDesc, &InitData, &VB);

    return true;
}
```

The Vertex Buffer is created Successfully, but I don't know how to send this data to be displayed on the screen. I am pretty new to DirectX 11, especially with the deprication of d3dx11.lib Please help me out here, and sorry if this post is garbage. I'm new to SO. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to read up more about the rendering pipeline. You need to set an input layout describing your vertex buffer which you set on to the IA (input assembler) part of the pipeline. Then you need to bind the VB you created to the IA stage as well. You will need to set up and set the appropriate shader programs (minimally a vertex shader and pixel shader) on the pipeline, and then finally, invoke a draw, matching the the corresponding primitive topology, followed by a present. This is assuming you have already set up your swapchain and backbuffer render targets. Luna and Zink books are good.

Comment: I wrote a comment and not an answer, because you clearly need to do more reading, and a complete answer is a lot of effort than can simply be replaced by googling any of the various online tutorials/samples and deconstructing them. Alternatively, if you aren't a complete beginner, you can start with the official howtos in the MSDN documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh404569%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Take a look at [DirectX Tool Kit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929) which provides a bunch of shared source helper utility code which should make life a lot easier for 'new to DirectX 11' people.